# Fuchs' theorem and ODE series solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have just learned to solve ODEs via power series method. I am a bit confused about the [Fuchs' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuchs%27s_theorem). The theorem mentions ordinary and regular singular points at $x_0$ and our ability to find the power series solution. What is $x_0$? Is it any point on the domain of the ODEs solution or is it a specific point? Is a power series (Frobenius) method based on fitting a series around the point or something else?

Comment: This question does not seem to have physical content. Perhaps [math.se] would be a better place to ask.

Comment: OK, let's close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your series expansion is taken about the point $x_{0}$, which may be an ordinary, regular singular, or irregular singular point.

Comment: But what is this $x_0$ point? Is it any point on the interval of the function? Is there any similarity with  $x_0$ and  $x=a$ in Taylor series, where we are building a series around a certain point?

Comment: It's exactly like in Taylor Series. If someone came up to you in the street with a differential equation and said "Find a series solution" then theu would need to give you a point about which to expand that series. Sometimes the solution at a particular point won't be very well defined - these are the singular points.